# How to insert Listbox items in MS Access database in a single row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code:

```
 Try
    Dim queryString As String
    queryString = "Insert into ServiceRecords([Personnel]) Values(@Personnels)"
    command1 = New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count + 1
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Personnels", ListBox1.Items(i))
        command1.Parameters.Clear()
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

But I get the error below, and I don't know how to fix it. I think it happens because of my code.

[image: error]

And this is what I get:

[image: result]

Comment: `.AddWithValue` is not the best choise. Try to use `.Add("Personnels",DbType.String).Value = ListBox1.Items(i))` instead.

Comment: You are going to go out of bounds on that loop due to the +1 and why area you clearing your parameter collection prior to the executeNonQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Let's review.

First, as muffi suggested, use the Add method instead of .AddWithValue but instead of DBType use OLEDBType. There is not .String type in OleDBType. You will have to check your Access db to get the correct datatype. Probably VarChar. In addition, the parameter name should match the parameter name in your query string. With Access the position is the important thing but with other databases the name matters.

Second, as Charles suggested, change the plus one to minus 1. Most people start counting at one but computers usually start at zero so the upper index of the ListBox is one less than the Count (remember you are starting at zero not one).

Third , as Charles also pointed out it is wrong to clear the parameters before you execute. Then you would have nothing in your parameter. It is not necessary to clear them at all because you are overwriting the Value property with each iteration of your loop and I have set the name and datatype outside the loop because they stay the same. We don't want to reset properties for each iteration when they don't change.

```
command1.Parameters.Add("@Personnels", OleDbType.VarChar)
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Count -1
    command1.Parameters("@Personnels").Value = ListBox1.Items(i)
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery
Next
```